# How to compile libsqlite3 for python without root privileges

Tags: python, linux, sqlite

I need to install python 3 in one web server(linux) and I do not have root access. So I just installed it in my home path. However, I cannot import sqlite from python command shell. I searched SO and found that I need to install libsqlite3. I have the following problems:

1. Now that I do not have root access, I need to compile libsqlite3 myself. But I do not have a trusted source code url, can anyone guide me there?
2. How can I make python to be aware of the library I compiled out of the libsqlite3 source code?

Comment: You really couldn't find sqlite.org?  http://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: @Paul, this is not libsqlite3, python needs more than sqlite head files